# Jira API : when using PUT call getting "no single-String constructor/factory method"

Tags: python, jira-rest-api

I was trying to update a custom field on a Jira ticket using Jira API, following this [Jira Documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-example-edit-issues-6291632/). however, I am getting the below error.

> {'errorMessages': ['Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueUpdateBean] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method']}

this is my code:

```
data = {'update': {'customfield_25305': [{'set': [{'value': '1c1a07d49af1b1cde8a1a7bd93cbbeef8efd50c9'}, {'value': 'c6f1e31ce0138cba658f769accaac729bebc42d6'}]}]}}

data = json.dumps(json.dumps(data)) #because the API accepts only strings enclosed in double quotes
upload = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=data)
print(upload.json())
```

as per the documentation, I tried "/editmeta" the custom field I am trying to update is editable and has the following attributes.

> {'required': False, 'schema': {'type': 'string', 'custom': 'com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:textfield', 'customId': 25305}, 'name': 'Commit ID(s)', 'fieldId': 'customfield_25305', 'operations': ['set']}

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, any help would be appreciated!

Tried [jira documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-example-edit-issues-6291632/)

and searched through the Jira community none of the answers helped, everything points to malformed data but the data that I am passing is as per documentation.

the end result would be a 204 status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue, the proper formatting for data is as below:

```
{"fields": {"customfield_25305": "\"1c1a07d49af1b1cde8a1a7bd93cbbeef8efd50c9\", \"c6f1e31ce0138cba658f769accaac729bebc42d6\", \"1c1a07d49af1b1cde8a1a7bd93cbbeef8efd50c9\""}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is a matter of single quotes.
As far as I remember, for valid JSON it should be double quotes.

```
{
    "update": {
        "customfield_25305": [{
            "set": [{
                "value": "1c1a07d49af1b1cde8a1a7bd93cbbeef8efd50c9"
            }, {
                "value": "c6f1e31ce0138cba658f769accaac729bebc42d6"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

I use to do a online validator tool to my JSON strings when I got stuck.
E.g. https://jsonlint.com/ (first result on google)

Comment: Thanks for responding. however, once I prepare the data with json.dumps(json.dumps()) it is a valid format, below is data.
```"{\"update\": {\"customfield_25305\": [{\"set\": [{\"value\": \"1c1a07d49af1b1cde8a1a7bd93cbbeef8efd50c9\"}, {\"value\": \"c6f1e31ce0138cba658f769accaac729bebc42d6\"}]}]}}"```  
I also verified on https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @TejasS have you tried to do one single set value? instead of 2. 
If makes any difference?

Comment: @TejasS. I just recheck my Jira implementation. (we build many years ago and I barely remember how to).
What I see for custom fields is that is needed another level .

Eg. 
"update":{ "fields": { "custom_field_25305": {"value":"1c1a07d49af1b1cde8a1a7bd93cbbeef8efd50c9"} } }

Comment: I tried that it did not work and a few other variations as well, but nothing worked.